# Including a Database file in build

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, xna

I have a game which uses a database to store some information. Is it possible to tell visual studio to include the datbase file with each build? Such that the `bin` folder will contain the application executable and the database. I know I can copy and paste the database each time but I want it to be automatic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You certainly can, one way to keep data being updated in the database is to change the DataBase's `Copy to output directory` property to `Copy if newer`; [ref](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/is/csharplanguage/thread/08738b94-1f93-429c-801f-2638d90dcbbc)

It depends on what kind of DB it is, but you can also right click your Project and choose `Add existing item`, navigate to file and presto.

Comment: I did add the database to my project (right click => include in project), but I think it is building it directly in the .exe. I need it to be on the outside. The include is working though, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There is a way: set the file's Copy to Output Directory property as `Copy Always` or `Copy if newer`.